# Grouping rows together in excel if they are scattered based on a field

Tags: excel

Lets say we have an excel with customerid and amount . If i sort the excel on amount my customers will be scattered. So i want to achieve sort and then group same customers amount tohether maintaining that sort.
If i have below

```
Row 1 .  X 200
Row 2.   Y 245
Row 3.   Z 45
Row 4.   Y 456
Row 5.   Z 23
Row 6.   T 5678
```

I want output as :

```
T 5678
Y 456
Y 245
X 200
Z 45
Z 23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select a single column and perform a sort, it disregards values from other columns. So, before sorting your Excel sheet, you need to select the **entire** sheet:

[image]

After that, choose "sort" from the menu, and select sort by column A and then by column B:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply , I have re phrased by requirement below , kindly help.

Answer (score -1):

Please see the sorted data on Column B (modified data for Z as 999).
[Sorted on Column B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKTb2.png)

Now below is the result i want to achieve.That is , after sorted on Column B , the rows should re-arrange such that the customers data gets together. Result as below, we can see that 2nd last row  z 999 had to be moved , putting below Z 23.

[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukGir.png)

Comment: This is not an answer to your question.  If you need to clarify your question, you should edit your original post. If you have not read about how this forum works, please start by taking the [2-minute tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Then explore the various [Help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help)